# Vectorize the operation based on 3 vectors to produce a matrix

Tags: matrix, vector

I have 3 vectors A, B and C of integers, where len(B) = len(C) I need to build a matrix X of (rows, columns)=(len(B), len(A)) based on these 3 vectors in the following way:

for any pair of integers (i, j) (i<rows and j<columns), if A[i] ==B[j], then X[j][i] =1, else if A[i] ==C[j] then X[j][i] =-1, else X[j][i] =0.

The following code works:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([3,6,12,14])
B=np.array([1,12,14,23,33])
C=np.array([3,6,16,28,37])

X=np.zeros((len(B),len(A))) 

for i in range(len(A)):

    for j in range(len(B)):

        if A[i]==B[j]:

            X[j][i]=1

        elif A[i]==C[j]:

            X[j][i]=-1
```

I would like to vectorize the operation as I have 3 huge vectors. I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.